# Two questions on Lebesgue integration and application of reverse triangle inequality

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm learning about measure theory (specifically Lebesgue integration) and need help with the following problem:

> Let $f_n, f \in L^1$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f_n-f\right| \rightarrow0$. Prove that $(1)$ $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}}f_n$ and $(2)$ $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f\right| = \lim \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f_n\right|$

I have found a solution for $(2)$ using the reverse triangle inequality but I don't understand how it works.

> $(2)$ If $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f_n-f\right| \rightarrow0$ then by the reverse triangle inequality 
>   $$0 \leq \left| \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f\right| - \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f_n\right|\right| \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f_n-f\right|.$$
>   Therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f_n\right| = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f\right|$.

I don't understand how the reverse triangle inequality works here using the assumption that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f_n-f\right| \rightarrow0$. Could someone explain this in more details? How do I show $(1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(1)$ note that
$$
\left| \int_{\mathbb{R}}f - \int_{\mathbb{R}}f_n\right| \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f_n-f\right|.
$$
For $(2)$ note that by this inequality
$$
\left| \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f\right| - \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f_n\right|\right| \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}\Big||f_n|-|f|\Big|\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f_n-f\right|.
$$
Letting $n\to\infty$ we obtain both properties, since
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left| \int_{\mathbb{R}}f - \int_{\mathbb{R}}f_n\right|=\left| \int_{\mathbb{R}}f - \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_n\right| 
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left| \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f\right| - \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f_n\right|\right| =\left| \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f\right| - \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f_n\right|\right|.
$$

Comment: Unfortunately it is still unclear to me why letting $n\to\infty$ yields both properties. Letting $n\to\infty$ both RHS of the inequalities tends to $0$ (by assumption), i.e. $$(1)\;\;\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}f-\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_n\right| \leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f_n-f\right|\to0$$ $$(2)\;\;\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f\right| - \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f_n\right|\right| \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}}\Big||f_n|-|f|\Big|\leq\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f_n-f\right| \to 0$$ but I don't see how I can conclude from here.

Comment: @Von Kar OK, I added the details to my answer.

Comment: Got it! Since both RHS are equal then $|a - b| = 0 \iff a = b$. Substituting $a$ and $b$ adequately in $(1)$ and $(2)$ proves both properties. Thank you for your detailed and clear explanation (and your time). It was extremely helpful and understandable.